# Avoir l'âge de raison ?

Tags: expressions, étymologie, sens, paroles-de-chanson

Il se trouve, [dans une chanson de Pierre Lalonde](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8S5BBbF2-U), les paroles suivantes :

> On a l'âge de raison mais on n'a jamais raison
>   A quoi bon en discuter quand les gens on leurs idées
>   Ils ne comprendront jamais

Je suis intéressé par la première partie, *On a l'âge de raison*. Que signifie cette expression ? Selon le contexte de la chanson, j'assumerais que cela signifie être d'un certain âge, la raison étant la sagesse accumulée. Mon interprétation est-elle correcte ? Si oui, quelle est l'origine de cette expression ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Exactement, la raison vient à un certain âge. Avoir l'âge de raison est donc avoir cet âge, où s'éveille le sens de la responsabilité.

Traditionnellement, en psychologie on associe l'âge de raison aux sept ans de l'enfant. Mais le chiffre 7 joue peut-être de son atout mystique ici.

Edit: L'usage écrit le plus ancien que j'ai trouvé est dans *Les diverses leçons de Pierre Messie* (1610 <sup>[google books](http://books.google.fr/books?id=-eXeKAuWo4kC&dq=%22age%20de%20raison%22&hl=fr&pg=PA487#v=onepage&q=%22age%20de%20raison%22&f=false)</sup>)

> Ne voyons nous pas les enfants des Turcs, qui devant qu'ils ayent aage de raison, abhorrissent nostre foy, & semblablement font les Juifs

ou en français moderne

> Ne voyons-nous pas les enfants des Turcs, qui avant-même qu'ils aient âge de raison, abhorrent notre foi, et les Juifs qui font de même

Comment: Je n'ai pas d'idée sur l'origine, mais je crois voir l'expression utilisée en 1579 par François Monsieur de Foix dans sa traudction du  _Pimandre de Mercure Trismégiste de la philosophie chrétienne,..._ (sur [gallica](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k110569f/f533.image)). Si quelqu'un veut faire la restranscription en commentaire... J'ai bien du mal à lire le vieux françois.

Comment: "et de ceux cy, il faut entre les uns estre hommes enfants de raison, & les autres sans l'age de raison" ?

Comment: Ah je m'étais donc trompé. L'âge de raison ne serait pas donc l'âge d'or, mais bien l'adolescence?

Comment: @Xeon06 Non, l'âge de raison arrive encore avant l'adolescence. L'âge de raison n'est pas une période (de X ans à Y ans), c'est un seuil, le moment à partir duquel on considère que l'enfant peut raisonner.

Comment: @rds Pas du tout : « Et de ceux cy, il faut entendre les uns esire (?) hommes usants de raison, et les autres sans usage de raison. »

Comment: @Gilles ah, merci pour la clarification. L'auteur semble donc assumer le role d'un enfant incompris par les adultes.

Comment: @Gilles merci et désolé pour la mauvaise piste. J'ai un ouvrage légèrement postérieur, mais je suis plus sûr de la retranscription cette fois (réponse éditée). Il me reste un "deuer" suspect (une forme ancienne de devoir?)

Comment: @rds « devant », signifiant ici *avant*. Messie dit que les Turcs et les Juifs détestent le christianisme avant de comprendre de quoi il retourne, c'est un exemple de préjugé.

Comment: @Gilles Encore merci (et réponse encore éditée:-)

Comment: Le chiffre sept n'a rien de mystique ici. Nombre d'instituteurs observent une évolution du comportement des enfants entre le CP (6 ans) et le CE1 (7 ans).

Comment: @mouviciel Ce que l'on peut supposer, en revanche, c'est que le symbole et la "valeur" mystique du chiffre ont simplement assuré une bonne presse à une donnée qui, au départ, est pourtant liée à des observations concrètes.

Answer (score 5):

L'âge de raison est l'âge à partir duquel une personne est jugée capable de raisonner, c'est-à-dire de penser, et éventuellement d'être moral. Le *Petit Robert* le définit comme « l'âge auquel on considère que l'enfant a l'essentiel de la raison », *raison* étant à prendre au sens de « la faculté de penser, en tant qu'elle permet à l'homme de bien juger et d'appliquer ce jugement à l'action ». Le *Trésor de la langue française* le définit comme l'[« âge auquel les enfants commencent à distinguer le bien du mal »](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A2ge). On dit aussi [quelquefois](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A2ge+de+raison%2C%C3%A2ge+de+discr%C3%A9tion&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3) *âge de discrétion*, le mot *discrétion* étant à prendre au sens (vielli) de faculté de discerner ([I.A](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/discr%C3%A9tion)) et non au sens plus courant de faible visibilité ou de modération.

Le terme vient du [droit canonique](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droit_canonique), c'est-à-dire des règlements de l'église catholique. Depuis le [quatrième concile du Latran](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quatri%C3%A8me_concile_du_Latran) au XIII<sup>e</sup> siècle, celui-ci [impose](http://www.vatican.va/archive/FRA0037/_P36.HTM) la [confession](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confession) et la [communion](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communion) à partir de l'*[annus](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/annus#Latin) [discretionis](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/discretio#Latin)*. La [confirmation](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation), qui marque l'entrée de l'enfant dans la vie religieuse, a lieu [autour de l'âge de raison](http://www.vatican.va/archive/FRA0037/_P30.HTM).

L'âge de raison est traditionnellement placé à 7 ans (aussi bien par les catholiques que par les psychologues), et il est assez courant de dire à un enfant lors de son septième anniversaire qu'il a atteint l'âge de raison. Noter que contrairement à d'autres expressions comme *âge mûr* ou *âge d'or*, l'âge de raison est un point dans le temps. L'expression « on a l'âge de raison » signifie donc littéralement que l'on a atteint (et passé) le moment où la raison apparaît.

La phrase citée signifie donc à peu près « on a beau être capable de penser, quand on discute avec d'autres, on n'est pas pris au sérieux, car les interlocuteurs ont leurs propres idées arrêtées, et il ne sert donc à rien de discuter puisqu'on ne les convaincra pas ».

Comment: Merci pour la réponse, surtout l'explication de la chanson!